# Is this a regression bug in Spark 1.3?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Without deprecation warnings in spark SQL 1.2.1, the following code stopped working in 1.3

**Worked in 1.2.1** (without any deprecation warnings)

```
 val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
 import sqlContext._
 val jsonRDD = sqlContext.jsonFile(jsonFilePath)
 jsonRDD.registerTempTable("jsonTable")

 val jsonResult = sql(s"select * from jsonTable")
 val foo = jsonResult.zipWithUniqueId().map {
   case (Row(...), uniqueId) => // do something useful
   ...
 }

 foo.registerTempTable("...")
```

**Stopped working in 1.3.0** (simply does not compile, and all I did was change to 1.3)

```
jsonResult.zipWithUniqueId() //since RDDApi doesn't implement that method
```

**Not working workaround:**

although this might give me an RDD[Row]:

```
jsonResult.rdd.zipWithUniqueId()
```

now this won't work as `RDD[Row]` does not have a `registerTempTable` method of course

```
     foo.registerTempTable("...")
```

**Here are my questions**

1. Is there a workaround? (e.g. am I simply doing it wrong?)
2. Is this a bug? (I think that anything that stops compiling that worked in a previous version, without a @deprecated warning is clearly a regression bug)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug, but sorry for the confusion! Up until Spark 1.3, Spark SQL was labeled an Alpha Component as the APIs were still in flux.  With Spark 1.3 we graduated and stabilized the API.  A full description of what you need to do when porting can be found in [the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#upgrading-from-spark-sql-10-12-to-13).

I can also answer your specific questions and give some justification about why we made these changes

> Stopped working in 1.3.0 (simply does not compile, and all I did was change to 1.3)
>   `jsonResult.zipWithUniqueId() //since RDDApi doesn't implement that method`

DataFrames are now one unified interface across both Scala and Java.  However, since we must maintain compatibility with the existing RDD API for the rest of 1.X, `DataFrames` are not `RDD`s.  To get the RDD representation you can call `df.rdd` or `df.javaRDD`

Additionally, because we were afraid of some of the confusion that can happen with implicit conversions, we made it such that you must explicitly call `rdd.toDF` to cause the conversion from RDD to occur.  However, this conversion only works automatically if your RDD holds objects that inherit from `Product` (i.e. tuples or case classes).

Back to the original question, if you want do to transformations on rows with arbitrary schema you will need to explicitly tell Spark SQL about the structure of the data after your map operation (since the compiler cannot).

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
val jsonData = sqlContext.jsonRDD(sc.parallelize("""{"name": "Michael", "zip": 94709}""" :: Nil))
val newSchema = 
  StructType(
    StructField("uniqueId", IntegerType) +: jsonData.schema.fields)

val augmentedRows = jsonData.rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map { 
  case (row, id) =>
    Row.fromSeq(id +: row.toSeq)
}

val newDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(augmentedRows, newSchema)
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I should have read the manual first ;) https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.3.0/sql-programming-guide.html#interoperating-with-rdds